# jQuery multiple selectors for existing jQuery objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to do a similar action when submitting two different forms:

I am able to do this using :

```
 $('#form1,#form2,').on('submit', function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    //Get action URL 
                    serviceUrl = $(this).attr('action')
                   //Dome something
                });
```

But is there a way to have multiple selectors when jQuery object is already declared?

```
var form1=$('#form1');
var form2=$('#form2');

 $($form1,$form2).on('submit', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                //Get action URL 
                serviceUrl = $(this).attr('action')
               //Dome something
            });
```

Comment: You can use [`.add()`](https://api.jquery.com/add/) method i.e. `$form1.add($form2).on(....)`

Comment: Thanks @Satpal, It solved my problem , if you could add this to answer , I will mark that as solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [.add()](https://api.jquery.com/add/) method

> Create a new jQuery object with elements added to the set of matched elements.

```
$form1.add($form2).on(...)
```